# A-Frame color change stops working after dynamically adding entities

Tags: angular, aframe

I'm using A-Frame to create a webapp/vrapp where I can add objects to the surface of another object (holds on a climbing wall) from an aframe object pool. For now, each hold is a sphere and I have a custom hover-color component that changes the color of the hold when the mouse hovers over it.

This hover-color component works as expected when the scene initially loads, this shows holds already in the database. However, after I add a new hold, the color change stops working for all holds. Interestingly, the corresponding console.log messages in the 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' event listeners stilll appear in the console, so the events themselves are still firing correctly.

Here is the hover-color component I'm using:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('hover-color', {
    schema: {
        color: {default: 'yellow'} // Color when hovered
    },

    init: function() {
        let data = this.data;
        let el = this.el;
        let originalColor = el.getAttribute('material').color;

        el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
            console.log(originalColor);
            el.setAttribute('material', 'color', data.color);
        });

        el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            console.log("mouseleave");
            el.setAttribute('material', 'color', originalColor);
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the function I'm using to add a hold to the scene:

```
addHold(location: THREE.Vector3, wallId: string, modelId: string) {
    let hold = this.createHoldFromPool(location);
    hold.setAttribute('class', 'intersectable');
    hold.setAttribute('hover-color', 'color: yellow');
}
```

The createHoldFromPool function retrieves an entity from a pool and places it at the specified location. After the hold is placed, it is given the intersectable class and the hover-color component is applied.

```
private createHoldFromPool(location: THREE.Vector3) {
  const holdContainer = document.querySelector('#hold-container');

  let holdPool = document.querySelector('#hold-pool');

  if(holdPool) {
    let holdPoolAny = <any>holdPool;
    var hold = holdPoolAny.components['pool__hold'].requestEntity();
    hold.play();
    if(holdContainer){
        hold.setAttribute('position', `${location.x} ${location.y} ${location.z}`);
        hold.setAttribute('hover-color', 'color: yellow');
        return hold
    }
 }
}
```

I've confirmed that the hover-color attribute is correctly set on the new hold after it's added. Additionally, the originalColor variable in the hover-color component seems to be set correctly as I can see them in the cnsole log. I'm not sure what's causing this issue and would appreciate any insight.

Comment: I recommend sharing full code that people can run and debug with https://glitch.com/~aframe If you can leave the angular pieces there will be more people that can help. best of luck